# How to make xcape work in ssh session

Tags: ssh, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to have <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> behave like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when combined with another key and <kbd>Esc</kbd> when pressed without combination.

I have added to my local machine's `.zshrc`:

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'
/usr/bin/xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape' -t 100
```

This works great when I work locally, but when I ssh into a server the <kbd>Esc</kbd> fuctionality stops working.

How can I make sure this also works when I ssh into another machine?

Comment: Sorry for the mis-edit, Peter!

Comment: @JeffSchaller No problem, keep up the good work!